# How can i overwrite any code in bootstrap4 using css?

Tags: css, bootstrap-4, overwrite

Can anyone please tell me how to overwrite css in bootstrap
E.g I want to add fonts and color to bootstrap carousel
If anyone knows please tell me

Answer (score 0):

if you want to add any style  you should overwrite it simply without adding important attributes if it will not work then make sure your CSS file is after the bootstrap file if it still is not implemented then apply a style with  !important like `div{color:#000!important;}`

Answer (score 0):

use !important in that style.
like `div{color:#000!important;}`